# Showing a set is a smooth manifold by constructing a diffeomorphism to a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I have two sets $M,N \subseteq \mathcal{E}$, which are subsets in a Euclidean space $\mathcal{E}$. I know, that $M$ is a smooth embedded manifold, and I have a diffeomorphism $\Psi:\mathcal{E} \rightarrow \mathcal{E}$ that maps $\mathcal{E}$ onto itself, while also $\Psi(M) = \Psi(N)$.

My question is, is there a clever/fast way of showing that $N$ must be also a smooth embedded manifold of the same dimension? Could I imply something about the tangent spaces of $N$ as well?

I understand that I could derive this from first principles, but is there maybe a theorem that would save the trouble?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by a diffeomorphism in this situation (since $N$ is not yet known to be a smooth submanifold)?

Comment: To talk about diffeomorphisms the source and the target of the maps should be smooth manifolds. Secondly, once you have a homeomorphism $\varphi:M\to N$, where $M$ is a manifold (respectively smooth manifolds) then $N$ is automatically a manifold (respectively smooth manifold), because the charts on $N$ can be constructed by sending the charts on $M$ with $\varphi$.

Comment: That is a good point, my apologies. I mean that I have a diffeomorphism mapping $\mathcal{E}$ onto itself, but also that maps $\Psi(M) = N$. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: What is the definition of embedded submanifold you use?

Comment: Defined by a smooth local defining function $h(x) = 0$ on $\mathcal{E}$.

Comment: Try to construct a local defining function on $\Phi (M)$ then (of course, using $h$ and $\Phi$)

Comment: In fact, it suffices to work with even a weaker notion of a diffeomorphism $f: M\to N$:  There exists $f^{-1}: N\to M$ such that both $f, f^{-1}$ extend to smooth maps $\phi: E\to E, \psi: E\to E$. (No need to require $\psi=\phi^{-1}$.) But the proof will be a bit more involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working  with embedded submanifolds i like to use the following theorems:

> If $S$ is a smooth embedded submanifold of $Y$, then the inclusion $S\hookrightarrow Y$ is a smooth immersion and a homeomorphism onto its image.

> If $f:X\to Y$ is a smooth immersion and a homeomorphism onto its image then $f(X)$ is an embedded submanifold of $Y$ and $f:X\to f(X)$ is a diffeomorphism.

Here $\mathrm{inc}\circ\Psi :M\to\mathcal E$ is a smooth immersion (as a composition of smooth immersions) and a homeomorphism onto its image (as the restriction of a homeomorphism). So its image $N$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathcal E$ and $\Psi_{|M}:M\to N$ is a diffeomorphism. In particular the dimensions of $M$ and $N$ are the same and the tangent space $T_pM$ gets mapped to $T_{\Psi(p)}N$ isomorphically by $d_p\Psi$.

But also using only the definition shouldn't cause too much trouble. For completeness:

Let $q\in N$ and set $p=\Psi^{-1}(q)$. Then there is an open set $U\subseteq\mathcal{E}$ containing $p$ and a smooth function $h:U\to\mathbb R^{n-k}$ with $n=\dim\mathcal{E}$ and $k=\dim M$ such that $0$ is a regular value of $h$ and $U\cap M=h^{-1}(0)$. Then $h\circ \psi^{-1}:\Psi(U)\to\mathbb R^{n-k}$ is a smooth function defined in an open neighbourhood of $p$ having $0$ as a regular value with
$$(h\circ \Psi^{-1})^{-1}(0)=\Psi(h^{-1}(0))=\Psi(U\cap M)=\Psi(U)\cap N$$
which shows that $N$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathcal{E}$.